# Configure Ngnix as reverse proxy without changing hostname

Tags: http, nginx, proxy

Due to some strange project requirements, I am trying to configure Ngnix as a reverse proxy which uses the same hostname that is specified in the incoming request, as the upstream gateway server.  The reason this should work is because the public internet DNS will point to our Ngnix server for a given hostname, but the local Ngnix server's resolve.conf will resolve the same hostname to a machine on the local network.

Here is what I have tried:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
   include           mime.types;
   default_type      application/octet-stream;
   sendfile          on;
   keepalive_timeout 65;

   server {
       listen       80;

       location / {
           resolver 127.0.0.1;
           proxy_pass http://$host;
       }
   }
}
```

I am seeing the following in the error log when I attempt to make a request:

> *1028 example.test.com could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "example.test.com", referrer: "http://foo.com/bar.htm"

When I ping the same hostname from the machine running Ngnix, it is resolved correctly and is reachable.

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver

Comment: ping is not a good test, try `dig` or `host`. Nginx requires a DNS resolver, it didn't use `gethostbyname`. If your host names are placed in /etc/hosts, Nginx can't use it. You need a caching resolver in this case, dnsmasq for example.

Answer (score 3):

We figured out that the problem had to do with our DNS resolver not supporting ipv6.  We disabled ipv6 within the Ngnix config file and it worked.  Just had to add "ipv6=off" after the dns resolver address.

Final config file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
   include           mime.types;
   default_type      application/octet-stream;
   sendfile          on;
   keepalive_timeout 65;

   server {
       listen       80;

       location / {
           resolver 127.0.0.1 ipv6=off;
           proxy_pass http://$host;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Adding ipv6=off after resolver didn't worked for me. What else could be the reason ?

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like this:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
   include           mime.types;
   default_type      application/octet-stream;
   sendfile          on;
   keepalive_timeout 65;

   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name example.test.com;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://192.168.x.x;
       }
   }

   server {
       listen       80;

       location / {
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
       }
   }
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Sorry, I didn't know you need a dynamic configure.  But it also need some configure in PROXY SERVER, I think.

Comment: he wants it dynamic not static.